# Unity3D - How can I detect collison between my car object and terrain?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a driving game for a project. My issue is that I'm unable to detect collision (I want to place the car to a checkpoint whenever it goes off the road) between the wheels of my car and the terrain. I tried to use this simple script but it does not seem to work:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class CarCollision: MonoBehaviour 
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) 
    {
        if (other.collider.name == "Terrain") 
        {
            Debug.Log("We got off the road!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `it does not seem to work` is a little bit broad ... have you tried [Debugging your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)? Is the method called at all? does the name match? Is there a collider on the terrain at all?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a 2d game? If yes, use OnCollisionEnter2D instead of OnCollisionEnter.

Is the script attached to the gameobject?

Are you sure that the terrain has a collider **which is not marked as trigger?**

Try copying and pasting this same thing in the main controller.

I hope it worked. Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it worked!